# Mapping one item posted in json object to the list object in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring, model-view-controller, list

I have in trouble with posting json object and mapping it with List object in Spring MVC controller. I have the form that has several checkboxes. When a user checks and submits, data in the form is deserialized, sent to Spring MVC controller and mapped to List type object. When a user checks two or more checkboxes, it works fine. but for just one box, it doesn't.

When a user checks two or more, the data is deserialized like below.

```
{"users":["137","138"]}
```

However, when a user checks just one checkbox, it is like

```
{"users":"138"}
```

and 400 bad request error is returned.

Is there any workaround or solution for this?

The jQuery codes are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#groupusers').submit(function() {
    var users = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.postJSON("${context}/admin/groups/${group.seq}/users", users, function(result) {
        ...
    });
    return false;
});
```

And the form is:

```
<form id="groupusers" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="edit_group">
  ...
  <div id="users">
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
      <label><input id="users" name="users" type="checkbox" value="${user.seq}" /> ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</label><br>
    </c:forEach>
  </div>
</form>
```

List object mapped to the form data:

```
public class AssignedUsers {
  private List<Long> users;
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you were able solve this problem. I'm having the same issues right now as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the implementation of the `serializeObject()` function? You might need to modify that to always return an array, so even if you only checked one box, the object should be: `{"users":["138"]}`

The server returned a 400 probably because the Jackson at threw a parsing exception at the backend.

Comment: serializeObject() seems coming from json library. (json.js) I'll look into that function. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### [Fojas' jQuery Serialize](https://github.com/fojas/jQuery-serializeObject)

This is the solution I have found and since been using which does excatly what you are requesting.

### Example

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="data[]" value="some data"/>
  <input name="data[]" value="more data"/>

  <input name="users[]" value="137"/>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#myForm').serializeObject();
```

Output

```
{
  data: ["some data", "more data"]
  users: [137]
}
```